# Why can I update the e-mail address, but not the billing address?

Tags: api, snipcart

I followed the doc at this page: https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/sdk/api#cart

I can update the cart like so:

```
Snipcart.api.cart.update({
  email: 'john.doe@example.com'
}).then(response => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update response", response);
}).catch(e => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update error", e);
});
```

However, when I try this:

```
Snipcart.api.cart.update({
  billingAddress:{
   name: 'John Doe'
 }
}).then(response => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update response", response);
}).catch(e => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update error", e);
});
```

I get:

```
Snipcart.api.cart.update error Object { kind: Getter & Setter, form: Getter & Setter, fields: Getter & Setter, … }
```

And I can't figure out why !? Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating billing address, you must set all billing address properties, otherwise the validation will fail.

You can try with:

```
Snipcart.api.cart.update({
  email: "johndoe@company.com",
  billingAddress:{
   ...address,
   name: 'John Doe'
 }
}).then(response => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update response", response);
}).catch(e => {
 console.log("Snipcart.api.cart.update error", e);
});
```

Comment: thanks, it (almost) worked for me. For it to work, you need to also pass the email in the payload, like so: email: "johndoe@company.com",
    billingAddress: {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address1": "226 rue St-Joseph E",
    "address2": "Suite 200",
    "city": "Quebec",
    "province": "QC",
    "country": "CA",
    "company": "Snipcart",
    "postalCode": "G1K3A9"
  }